# Dynamic Programming: Sum-of-products

Tags: algorithm, statistics, dynamic-programming

Let's say you have two lists, L1 and L2, of the same length, N.  We define prodSum as:

```
def prodSum(L1, L2) :
    ans = 0
    for elem1, elem2 in zip(L1, L2) :
        ans += elem1 * elem2

    return ans
```

Is there an efficient algorithm to find, assuming L1 is sorted, the number of permutations of L2 such that prodSum(L1, L2) < some pre-specified value?

If it would simplify the problem, you may assume that L1 and L2 are both lists of integers from [1, 2, ..., N].

Edit:  Managu's answer has convinced me that this is impossible without assuming that L1 and L2 are lists of integers from [1, 2, ..., N].  I'd still be interested in solutions that assume this constraint.

Comment: Are you asking for sum ? or u asking for a specified value where prodSum(L1,L2) < X ?

Comment: Not homework.  This is actually a problem that I need to solve to compute a statistical function.  I stripped it of that context because it would have made the problem unnecessarily complicated for non-statisticians.

Comment: do you mean that we may assume L1=range(1,n) and L2=range(1,m)?  I.e. each is a list of _all_ integers up to some point?

Comment: Right.  Only if you assume this, n is also equal to m, because len(L1) == len(L2).

Comment: Seems I was totally wrong on my lex-order approach (just tested it).  Sorry bout that

Comment: Maybe you could indicate some of the context that you've stripped away?  Who knows, it might help.

Comment: This is actually for calculating exact P-values for Spearman's Rho (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rho).  For fixed marginal distributions (which you have if your marginals are ranks and there are no ties) the test statistic is a simple function of the sum-of-products.  I didn't put this context here because about 99% of programmers have probably never heard of Spearman's Rho and I figured it would mostly just confuse people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to first dispell a certain amount of confusion about the math, then discuss two solutions and give code for one of them.

There is a counting class called #P which is a lot like the yes-no class NP.  In a qualitative sense, it is even harder than NP.  There is no particular reason to believe that this counting problem is any better than #P-hard, although it could be hard or easy to prove that.

However, many #P-hard problems and NP-hard problems vary tremendously in how long they take to solve in practice, and even one particular hard problem can be harder or easier depending on the properties of the input.  What NP-hard or #P-hard mean is that there are hard cases.  Some NP-hard and #P-hard problems also have less hard cases or even outright easy cases.  (Others have very few cases that seem much easier than the hardest cases.)

So the practical question could depend a lot on the input of interest.  Suppose that the threshold is on the high side or on the low side, or you have enough memory for a decent number of cached results.  Then there is a useful recursive algorithm that makes use of two ideas, one of them already mentioned:  (1) After partially assigning some of the values, the *remaining* threshold for list *fragments* may rule out all of the permutations, or it may allow all of them.  (2) Memory permitting, you should cache the subtotals for some remaining threshold and some list fragments.  To improve the caching, you might as well pick the elements from one of the lists in order.

Here is a Python code that implements this algorithm:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
size = len(list1)
threshold = 396     # This is smack in the middle, a hard value

cachecutoff = 6     # Cache results when up to this many are assigned

def dotproduct(v,w):
    return sum([a*b for a,b in zip(v,w)])

factorial = [1]
for n in xrange(1,len(list1)+1):
    factorial.append(factorial[-1]*n)

cache = {}

# Assumes two sorted lists of the same length

def countprods(list1,list2,threshold):
    if dotproduct(list1,list2) <= threshold:            # They all work
        return factorial[len(list1)]
    if dotproduct(list1,reversed(list2)) > threshold:   # None work
        return 0
    if (tuple(list2),threshold) in cache:               # Already been here
        return cache[(tuple(list2),threshold)]
    total = 0
    # Match the first element of list1 to each item in list2
    for n in xrange(len(list2)):
        total += countprods(list1[1:],list2[:n] + list2[n+1:],
            threshold-list1[0]*list2[n])
    if len(list1) >= size-cachecutoff:
        cache[(tuple(list2),threshold)] = total
    return total

print 'Total permutations below threshold:',
print countprods(list1,list2,threshold)
print 'Cache size:',len(cache)
```

As the comment line says, I tested this code with a hard value of the threshold.  It is quite a bit faster than a naive search over all permutations.

There is another algorithm that is better than this one if three conditions are met:  (1) You don't have enough memory for a good cache, (2) the list entries are small non-negative integers, and (3) you're interested in the hardest thresholds.  A second situation to use this second algorithm is if you want counts for all thresholds flat-out, whether or not the other conditions are met.  To use this algorithm for two lists of length n, first pick a base x which is a power of 10 or 2 that is bigger than n factorial.  Now make the matrix

```
M[i][j] = x**(list1[i]*list2[j])
```

If you compute the permanent of this matrix M using the [Ryser formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_the_permanent_of_a_matrix), then the kth digit of the permanent in base x tells you the number of permutations for which the dot product is exactly k.  Moreover, the Ryser formula is quite a bit faster than the summing over all permutations directly.  (But it is still exponential, so it does not contradict the fact that computing the permanent is #P-hard.)

Also, yes it is true that the set of permutations is the symmetric group.  It would be great if you could use group theory in some way to accelerate this counting problem.  But as far as I know, nothing all that deep comes from that description of the question.

Finally, if instead of exactly counting the number of permutations below a threshold, you only wanted to *approximate* that number, then probably the game changes completely.  (You can approximate the permanent in polynomial time, but that doesn't help here.)  I'd have to think about what to do; in any case it isn't the question posed.

---

I realized that there is another kind of caching/dynamic programming that is missing from the above discussion and the above code.  The caching implemented in the code is early-stage caching:  If just the first few values of list1 are assigned to list2, and if a remaining threshold occurs more than once, then the cache allows the code to reuse the result.  This works great if the entries of list1 and list2 are integers that are not too large.  But it will be a failed cache if the entries are typical floating point numbers.

However, you can also precompute at the other end, when most of the values of list1 have been assigned.  In this case, you can make a sorted list of the subtotals for all of the remaining values.  And remember, you can use up list1 in order, and do all of the permutations on the list2 side.  For example, suppose that the last three entries of list1 are [4,5,6], and suppose that three of the values in list2 (somewhere in the middle) are [2.1,3.5,3.7].  Then you would cache a sorted list of the six dot products:

```
endcache[ [2.1, 3.5, 3.7] ] = [44.9, 45.1, 46.3, 46.7, 47.9, 48.1]
```

What does this do for you?  If you look in the code that I did post, the function countprods(list1,list2,threshold) recursively does its work with a sub-threshold.  The first argument, list1, might have been better as a global variable than as an argument.  If list2 is short enough, countprods can do its work much faster by doing a binary search in the list endcache[list2].  (I just learned from stackoverflow that this is implemented in the bisect module in Python, although a performance code wouldn't be written in Python anyway.)  Unlike the head cache, the end cache can speed up the code a lot even if there are no numerical coincidences among the entries of list1 and list2.  Ryser's algorithm also stinks for this problem without numerical coincidences, so for this type of input I only see two accelerations:  Sawing off a branch of the search tree using the "all" test and the "none" test, and the end cache.

Answer (score 7):

Probably not (without the simplifying assumption): your problem is NP-Hard.  Here's a trivial reduction to [SUBSET-SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  Let `count_perms(L1, L2, x)` represent the function "count the number of permutations of L2 such that prodSum(L1, L2) < x"

```
SUBSET_SUM(L2,n): # (determine if any subset of L2 adds up to n)
    For i in [1,...,len(L2)]
        Set L1=[0]*(len(L2)-i)+[1]*i
        calculate count_perms(L1,L2,n+1)-count_perms(L1,L2,n)
        if result positive, return true
    Return false
```

Thus, if there were a way to calculate your function `count_perms(L1, L2, x)` efficiently, then we would have an efficient algorithm to calculate SUBSET_SUM(L2,n).

Comment: Note `prodSum` is the dot product. Let `N = len(L2)`. Then `prodSum([1]*N, L2) == sum(L2)`. Since addition is commutative, `count_perms(L1, L2, x) == N!` if `x > sum(L2)` and `count_perms(L1, L2, x) == 0` if `x <= sum(L2)`. Thus `count_perms(L1,L2,n)-count_perms(L1,L2,n-1)` is either N! or 0. Since quite a few subset sums aren't of either form, the above algorithm does not solve subset-sum.

Comment: Good catch.  Let's add another loop (still a polynomial time reduction).

Answer (score 2):

This also turns out to be an abstract algebra problem. It's been awhile for me, but here's a few things to get started. There's nothing terribly significant about the following (it's all very basic; an expansion on the fact that every group is isomorphic to a permutation group), but it provides a different way of looking at the problem.

I'll try to stick to fairly standard notation: "**x**" is a vector, and "**x**<sub>i</sub>" is the i<sup>th</sup> component of **x**. If "L" is a list, **L** is the equivalent vector. "**1**<sup>n</sup>" is a vector with all components = 1. The set of natural numbers ℕ is taken to be the positive integers. "[a,b]" is the set of integers from a through b, inclusive. "θ(**x**, **y**)" is the angle formed by **x** and **y**

Note `prodSum` is the dot product. The question is equivalent to finding all vectors **L** generated by an operation (permuting elements) on L2 such that θ(**L1**, **L**) less than a given angle α. The operation is equivalent to reflecting a point in ℕ<sup>n</sup> through a subspace with presentation:

> < ℕ<sup>n</sup> | (**x**<sub>i</sub>**x**<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup>)<sub>(i,j) ∈ A</sub> >

where i and j are in [1,n], `A` has at least one element and no (i,i) is in `A` (i.e. `A` is a non-reflexive subset of [1,n]<sup>2</sup> where |`A`| > 0). Stated more plainly (and more ambiguously), the subspaces are the points where one or more components are equal to one or more other components. The reflections correspond to matrices whose columns are all the standard basis vectors.

Let's name the reflection group "RP<sub>n</sub>" (it should have another name, but memory fails). RP<sub>n</sub> is isomorphic to the symmetric group S<sub>n</sub>. Thus

> |RP<sub>n</sub>| = |S<sub>n</sub>| = n!

In 3 dimensions, this gives a group of order 6. The reflection group is D<sub>3</sub>, the triangle symmetry group, as a subgroup of the cube symmetry group. It turns out you can also generate the points by rotating **L2** in increments of π/3 around the line along **1**<sup>n</sup>. This is the the modular group ℤ<sub>6</sub> and this points to a possible solution: find a group of order n! with a minimal number of generators and use that to generate the permutations of L2 as sequences with increasing, then decreasing, angle with **L2**. From there, we can try to generate the elements **L** with θ(**L1**, **L**) < α directly (for example we can binsearch on the 1st half of each sequence to find the transition point; with that, we can specify the rest of the sequence that fulfills the condition and count it in O(1) time). Let's call this group RP'<sub>n</sub>.

RP'<sub>4</sub> is constructed of 4 subspaces isomorphic to ℤ<sub>6</sub>. More generally, RP'<sub>n</sub> is constructed of n subspaces isomorphic to RP'<sub>n-1</sub>.

This is where my abstract algebra muscles really begins to fail. I'll try to keep working on the construction, but Managu's answer doesn't leave much hope. I fear that reducing RP<sub>3</sub> to ℤ<sub>6</sub> is the only useful reduction we can make.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if l1 and l2 are both ordered high->low (or low->high, whatever, if they have the same order), the result is maximized, and if they are ordered oposite, the result is minimized, and other alterations of order appear to follow some rules; swapping two numbers in a continuous list of integers always reduces the sum by a fixed amount which seems to be related to their distance apart (ie swapping 1 and 3 or 2 and 4 have the same effect).  This was just from a little messing around, but the idea is that there is a maximum, a minimum, and if some-pre-specified-value is between them, there are ways to count the permutations that make that possible (although; if the list isn't evenly spaced, then there aren't.  Well, not that I know of.  If l2 is (1 2 4 5) swapping 1 2 and 2 4 would have different effects)